# How can I calaculate this complex series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Let $A=\{a+bi|a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\}-\{0\}$

For what $n$ does $\sum_{z \in A} 1/z^n$ $(n\in \mathbb{N})$ converge?

If it converges, how can I evaluate it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $n\not\equiv0\pmod4$ then the sum evaluates to $0$. This follows from the fact that $(-z)^n=-z^n$ for odd $n$, and $(iz)^n=-z^n$ for $n\equiv2\pmod4$, making all terms cancel out either pairwise or in quadruples.

The sum converges for $n>1$, though evaluating it is in general not easy.

Comment: @Surb The summation presented is indeed a subtle one, because it is an infinite summation. However, for $n>1$ this sum is absolutely convergent, so rearrangement of the terms is not a problem.